# creating table in python with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

New to python here and I have a question about creating a table from a scrape using Beautiful soup. Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
page=requests.get("https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/lobbyist.php?id=Y0000008510L&year=2018")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
table=soup.find(‘table’,{‘id’:’lobbyist_summary’})
for row in table:
    cells=row.find_all(‘a’)
    rn=cells[0].get_text()
```

Error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

print(table) looks like this:

```
[<a href="firmsum.php?id=D000037635&amp;year=2018">Ballard Partners</a>, <a href="clientsum.php?id=F203227&amp;year=2018">Advanced Roofing Inc</a>, <a href="clientsum.php?id=F214670&amp;year=2018">Africell Holding</a>, <a href="clientsum.php?id=D000023883&amp;year=2018">Amazon.com</a>, ...]
```

I would like to (eventually) end up with a table that has each element of interest in a separate column so that it looks like:

[[firmsum,D000037635,2018,Ballard Partners],[clientsum,F203227,2018,Advanced Roofing Inc],[clientsum,F214670,2018,Africell Holding],[clientsum,D000023883, 2018, Amazon.com]...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign 4 empty lists:

```
col1List = list()
col2List = list()
col3List = list()
col4List = list()
```

First, let's get the column 4 values:

```
trs = table.find_all('tr')[1]
tds = trs.find_all('a')

for i in range(len(tds)):
    col4List.append(tds[i].get_text())
```

This gives:

```
['Ballard Partners', 'Advanced Roofing Inc', 'Africell Holding',....]
```

Now, let us extract the values for first 3 columns from `href`:

```
hrefVal = trs.find_all('a')

for i in hrefVal:
    hVal = i.get('href')
    col11 = hVal.split('.php?id=', 1)
    col1 = col11[0]
    col1List.append(col1)
    col22 = col11[1].split('&', 1)
    col2 = col22[0]
    col2List.append(col2)
    col33 = col22[1].split('=', 1)
    col3 = col33[1]
    col3List.append(col3)
```

Now, let us put all the lists in a dataframe to make it look neat:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Col1'] = col1List
df['Col2'] = col2List
df['Col3'] = col3List
df['Col4'] = col4List
```

If I output the first few rows, it will look like how you want it:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3    Col4
firmsum     D000037635  2018    Ballard Partners
clientsum   F203227     2018    Advanced Roofing Inc
clientsum   F214670     2018    Africell Holding
clientsum   D000023883  2018    Amazon.com
clientsum   D000000192  2018    American Health Care Assn
clientsum   D000021839  2018    American Road & Transport Builders Assn
```

Comment: trollster: You are awesome! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this!